# How to refresh tableview when user inserts an item into the database?

Tags: swift, sqlite

When the user inserts an item into the database and then clicks the back button to return to the tableview, the tableview is not displaying the new item. I have to stop the app, and run it again for the new item to be displayed. My database is working perfectly fine, so i don't think thats the problem.

I do reload the database again in the mainController inside ViewDidLoad(). I also tried doing tableView.reloadData() inside ViewDidLoad() as well and that doesn't do anything.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?
    let mainDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // read from the database
        mainDelegate.readDataFromDatabase()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return mainDelegate.people.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookTableViewCell") as! BookTableViewCell

        let rowNum = indexPath.row

        cell.lblTitle?.text = mainDelegate.people[rowNum].title
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

        return cell
    }



class NewBookItemViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var titletxt : UITextField!

    @IBAction func buttonSave(sender: UIButton){
         // step 18b - instantiate Data object and add textfield data
            let person : Data = Data.init()
            person.initWithData(theRow: 0, thetitle: title)

            let mainDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

            // step 18c - do the insert into db
            let returnCode : Bool = mainDelegate.insertIntoDatabase(person: person)      


        }
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` will not be called when returning from another presented UIViewController. It's already "loaded". You can try `viewWillAppear`. There are also other means of communicating information back to the presenting controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  mainDelegate.readDataFromDatabase()
  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

As `viewDidLoad` is called once when the vc is loaded , also it's not the responsiliblity of the appDelegate to do such things , conside having a dataSource class that handle read/write from the database